# Fingerprint scanner futronic FS80 integration with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, fingerprint

I am developing a C# program in WPF which scans a fingerprint, stores it somewhere on local disk and then read it in another program for further manipulation.
For fingerprint scanning, i am having futronic device FS80. I have got all the required dlls in the CD but the biggest problem for me is those dlls are not valid COM components so not able to add them as a reference in my project. Anyhow I managed to add them using dllImport through coding but now I dont know which are the functions the dll contains and what are their parameters and use.
Totally stuck at the first phase only. Very frustrating because its my first attemp with wpf and device integration.
Can anyone please guide me how to integrate FS80?
I searched on futronic site but they are only providing sample exe and no code.
If anyone is having any type of idea please share.

Answer (score 0):

I found something helpful.
http://read.pudn.com/downloads110/sourcecode/math/457634/FingerprintDemo/fingerprint/ftr%20scanner/ftrScanAPI.h__.htm

It is not in C# but it will give an idea